# Best way to implement a Reverse MultiMap

Tags: java, string, arraylist, data-structures

My Java8 program has several stages:

A `CSV file` is parsed. The `CSV file` looks like this:

```
123,[Foo:true; Bar:true; Foobar:false; Barfoo:false]
456,[Foobar:true; Barfoo:false; Foo:false; Bar:false]
789,[Foobar:true; Barfoo:false; Foo:false]
```

where **123**, **546** and **789** are unique identifiers of each datastructure, one datastructure is represented by the *column identifiers* `Foo` `Bar` `Foobar` and `Barfoo`, where each boolean indicates, if the column is a *key-colum*.

While the `CSV file` is parsed, for each line a datastructure must be created.

Later, in runtime, wich needs to be fast, the following will happen:

An `ArrayList<String>` containing *column data* is given. Data needs to be added to a specific datastructure. (I do now the unique identifier 123).

1. Say: the `ArrayList<String>` needs to be added to **123**: 1-> `foo`, 2->`bar`, 3-> `foobar`, 4 ->`barfoo`.
2. Say: another `ArrayList<String>` needs to be added to **456**: 1-> `foobar`, 2-> `barfoo`
3. Say: another `ArrayList<String>` needs to be added to **789**: 1-> `foobar`, 2-> `null`, 3-> `foo`

The tasks that the datastructure needs to provide are the following:

1. add(`ArrayList<String>`) : void
2. remove(`ArrayList<String>`) : boolean (if successfull)
3. contains(`Arraylist<String>`) : boolean
4. get(`ArrayList<String>`)  : `ArrayList<String>`

**Notes:**

1. The combination of all keys inside of one datastructure **123** are unique. Meaning: If in **123** is one entry with `foo`,`bar`,`foobar`, `barfoo`, Another enrty with `foo`,`bar`,`doesnt matter`, `neither` will not be allowed. Another enrty with `foo1`,`bar`, `foobar`,`barfoo` is allowed, as well as an entry with `foo1`,`bar1`,`foobar`, `barfoo` is also allowed.
2. It won't happen, that wile parsing, a *column name* not beeing a key (true), is in front of a key. This will not happen:

   ```
   [Foobar:true;Barfoo:false;Foo:true;Bar:false]
   ```
3. It won't happen, at runtime, that a column marked as a `key` will not get data: This will not happen: an `ArrayList<String>` added to **123** with data looks like this: 1->`foo`, 2->`null`, 3->`foobar`.

**I tried:** storing at each datastructure-class two arrays. One with the Column Names, and one with Numbers of the Columns, which are keys. At runtime the key-indicating array will be processed to get all key values (at the first add example above it would be `foo` and `bar`) and they will be concatenated. (to a String `"foo,bar"`). This is a new key for a second `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>` where the value (`ArrayList<String>`) contains the data of all columns (`foo`,`bar`,`foobar`,`barfoo`).

I have a `getKeyString` method:

```
String getKeyString(ArrayList<String> keys, ArrayList<Integer> keyPos){
if (keyPos.get(keyPos.size()-1) >= keys.size())  //if the last entry from orders arraylist keyPos is greater than size of keys
    throw new Exception();
String collect = keyPos.stream().map(i -> keys.get(i))
        .map(string ->{
            try{
                if(string.equals("null")) // happens not very often, ~1time in 1,000
                    return ""; 
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e) { //happens even less 1 in 100,000
                return "";
            }
                    return string;
            })
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

if(collect.length()<keyPos.size())
    throw new Exception("results in an empty key: ");   

return collect;
```

and the addDataListEnty looks quite similar to this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dataLists = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> keyPos = new ArrayList<>();

...

public void addDataListEntry(ArrayList<String> values) {
    // will overwrite Entry if it already exists
    try {
        this.dataLists.put(getKeyString(values, keyPos), values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This does actually work, but is really slow, since the key (`foo,bar`) needs to created at every datastructure-access.

Which combination of HashMaps, Lists, Sets, (even Google Guava) is the best to make it as fast as possible?

Comment: In short, your problem seems to be that the current implementation works but is slow. Could you post the _actual code_ that's slow because it's quite relevant for solving the problem.

Comment: Do you want more code... ? Beacuse I actually dont want to influence with my crappy code. Im searching for a whole new Structure, and not trying to improve the existing one...

Comment: Looks like you need a Map of Maps...